# How to find control created by codebehind using name in WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, findname

I am currently attempting to create a MIPS emulator using WPF.

In a stack panel control called **registerList**; I created 32 stack panels (named C0 to C31) that each contain 2 textblocks (second textblock named R0 to R31).

I initially display the 32 registers contained on **Procesor.RegisterBank.Registers[i]** correctly using the **displayRegisters()** method I created.

I made a method to update all 32 values of second textblocks with the values contained on a class called **Procesor.RegisterBank**.

However when attempting to use this method, the GUI page will not display when I start the project.

I've been stuck on this for hours and almost considering not creating the stack panels via code.

Thanks

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MRA.MRA Procesor = new MRA.MRA();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        displayRegisters();
        Procesor.RegisterBank.registers[1] = 69;
        updateRegisters();
    }

    public void updateRegisters()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Procesor.RegisterBank.registers.Length; i++)
        {
            var register = (StackPanel)registerList.FindName("C"+i.ToString());
            var content = (TextBlock)register.FindName("R"+i.ToString());
            content.Text= Procesor.RegisterBank.registers[i].ToString();
        }
    }

    public void displayRegisters()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Procesor.RegisterBank.registers.Length; i++)
        {
            var register = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal, Background = Brushes.White, Margin = new Thickness(6, 6, 6, 6), MinHeight = 25, Name = "C" + i.ToString() };
            var registerName = new TextBlock { Text = "R"+i.ToString(), FontSize = 16, MinWidth = 30, Background = Brushes.DarkGray, Foreground = Brushes.White};
            var registerValue = new TextBlock { Text = Procesor.RegisterBank.registers[i].ToString(), FontSize = 16, MinWidth = 100, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right, Name="R"+i.ToString()};
            register.Children.Add(registerName);
            register.Children.Add(registerValue);
            registerList.Children.Add(register);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "almost considering not creating the stack panels via code."  Almost. You almost considered doing it right, but that would be too easy. I suggest you either use winforms, or use WPF properly. Trying to use WPF as winforms ends in anguish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [RegisterName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername(v=vs.110).aspx) , so that newly added `Control` can be part of the `NameScope` of parent control.

Add these lines at the end in your `displayRegister()` method :

`NameScope.SetNameScope(register, new NameScope());`
`register.RegisterName(registerValue.Name, registerValue);`
`registerList.RegisterName(register.Name, register);`